# Windows stuck on BSOD with error KMODE EXCEPTION NOT HANDLED

Tags: windows, boot

Last morning I turned on my PC only to find out that it doesn't start, and it's stuck in a blue screen loop, with the message "KMODE Exception Not Handled". See picture [here](https://imgur.com/rPkYiva)

I have searched this problem and found out that it might be a corrupted drive, or some sort? I have tried booting Windows to safe mode but it simply cannot be done and not sure why. I have downloaded the Windows Media Installation file on a stick, and saw that I need to write this command in cmd:

`bcdedit /set {default} safeboot minimal`

Still no result as I get the error:

"The boot configuration data store could not be opened 
The requested system device cannot be found"

I've tried the F8 trick but it's not working, I have rebuilt the bcd and still no result, as I get another error at the end "The requested system device cannot be found". See picture [here](https://imgur.com/ErJfEsc)

I have also tried to create a recovery drive from another PC in order to get into safe mode but still no result..

What do you think I should do, or what do you think the problem is? I don't really want to reinstall Windows and lose all my items on my drives.

Thank you!

Comment: I have seen that picture numerous times.  Start over.  Maybe simplify your installation to make error recovery easier.

Comment: There are multiple issues going on that likely have nothing to do with the other - the Kernel error can be a result of many things - what version of Windows are you running, and if a laptop, was it manufactured prior to Windows 10's release or came pre-installed with Windows 8? The BCD Store and boot device likely has nothing to do with the Kernel error - did you change anything in the BIOS/UEFI firmware settings? If UEFI, is CSM [Legacy] Mode enabled _(it should never be)_? _(Cont'd...)_

Comment: _(Cont'd...)_ The BCD Store can't be found likely because the boot partition cannot be found _(vital details requested above are missing, such as changes to BIOS/UEFI firmware settings or a reset of, as the drive type being changed from `AHCI` to `RAID`, etc. will also result in an inaccessible boot device)_ - from WinPE/WinRE, run `chkdsk <drive>: /OfflineScanAndFix` to fix a corrupted filesystem, and if the BCD Store still can't be accessed once the boot drive is accessible, to fix: `BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD`

Comment: Hi! I am on a desktop computer running Windows 10. I have updated the BIOS to the latest version a few months ago, but did not encounter any problem. I tried your commands but no result. I'm not really familiar with AHCI/RAID and UEFI